# Bash script, need help⠀with homework assignment

Tags: bash, shell

I have homework (Shell script) which I tried my best to make it work, but in vain.

Can anyone help?

Question:

Write a bash program named fix-permissions.sh that accepts a list of users as arguments.

1. If one user or more are given as arguments, the script should reset file permissions as follows:

   a. Directory ~/share to 750 (if it exists).
   b. All regular files inside ~/share to 744.
   c. All directories inside ~/share to 750.
   d. All other regular files in ~ to 600 and all other directories in ~ to 700.
   e. files of other types are left as they are.

   We assume that there is only one level of files and directories inside ~ (except for ~/share), and there is only one level of files and directories inside ~/share.
2. If no arguments are given, the script should identify normal users in the system (UID >= 500) and for each user, reset files permissions as described above.
3. At the end of execution, this script must generate a file named report.txt that contains a list of all files in the user's home directory including full path, owner, group and permissions for each file.

---

What I have now looks like this:

[*...and there is nothing...back to the revision history - this is from Revision 4...*]

#### Part 1

```
#!/bin/bash

#$ fx-permiss.sh user1 user2 user3

for user ; do
if -d /home/$user/share ; then
chmod 750 /home/$user/share ; else
echo “No folder named “share” is in $user home directory”
fi

find /home/$user/share -type f -exec chmod 744 {} \;
find /home/$user/share -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
find ~ -type f -not \( -name share -o -name ~ \) -exec chmod 600
find ~ -type d -not \( -name share -o -name ~ \) -exec chmod 700

done
```

#### Part 2

If no arguments are give, the script should identify normal users in the system (UID >= 500) and for each user, reset files permissions as described above.

```
for User in $(cat /etc/passwd) ; do
UserId=$(echo $User | cut -d ":" -f 3)
if ($UserId -gt 500) ; then
# reset permission 
fi
done
```

#### Part 3

At end of execution, produce a file named report.txt that contains a list of all files in the user's home directory including full path, owner, group and permissions for each file.

```
find . -ls | awk '{print $user1 "\t" $5 "\t" $6 "\t" $user}' | tee report.txt
#it should be for all users
#where it should be saved?

chmod 755 fix-permissions

exit 0
```

Comment: Although this seems like a great question, I'm afraid I'm not quite up to the challenge.  You might repost/migrate this to one of the other boards--there is Server Fault and Unix/Linux both of which should be able to give a quicker/better answer.  Or someone will post a great answer by the time I've hit add comment and I'll look even stupider.

Comment: It does not seem to work properly ... What happened ? The script will process three users given as arguments, and then all users in the '/etc/passwd'

Comment: this looks like fun, hopefully i'll be back in a bit with some help

Comment: Post what it's doing, both correctly and incorrectly.  Note too that there is no point in your 2 find lines if the directory doesn't exist (that's a hint).  Note too that 'in $1 $2 $3' assumes three arguments, but you don't know how many you have (and it directly contradicts your later 'shift' command)

Comment: Why was your original code deleted?  It should be left there for posterity.

Comment: unfortunately I didn't clipboard it.

Comment: I only have the first half (the 'corrected' first half)

Answer (score 5):

code from the initial post seems to have disappeared... rolled up an example.

```
#!/bin/bash

function mod {
    if [ -d "/Users/$1/share" ]; then
        echo "permissions changes for $1"
        #chmod 750 /Users/$1/share
        #find /Users/$1/share -type f -exec chmod 744 {} \;
        #find /Users/$1/share -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
        #find /Users/$1/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
        #find /Users/$1/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
    fi   
}

function clean {
    IFS=':' read -ra pw <<< "$1"
    local c=0
    local n=""
    local t=500
    for i in "${pw[@]}"; do 
        if [ $c == 0 ]; then
            n="$i"
        fi
        if [ $c == 2 ]; then
            if [ "$i" -gt "$t" ]; then
                mod $n
            fi
        fi
        c=$[$c+1]
    done
}

function report {
    export user=$(whoami)
    ls -la "/Users/$user" > report.txt
}

if [ -z $1 ]; then"
    while read line; do 
        if [ "${line:0:1}" != "#" ]; then
            clean $line
        fi
    done < /etc/passwd
else
    for arg in "$@"
       do
         mod $arg
       done
fi
report
```

only requirement that it doesn't meet is printing full path (only prints relative) under #3 in the report. the variable t is the lowest uid the permissions changes will affect. commented out the chmods so no one accidentally does this to their system. oops.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying $1 $2 $3, loop over the inputs like so:

```
for user ; do
```

Then, you will need to change all $1 to $user

Comment: You almost never want `$*`. Use `"$@"` instead. Or just remove the sequence to iterate over entirely; the default for `for` is `$@`.

Comment: I hadn't realized the difference between the variables.  I'll update to reflect that.

Comment: You won't need the shift before done, aside from that, its better.  Although, please reformat the code to display as code.